# Parallel Connection of ICs

Tags: voltage, mosfet, current, driver, mosfet-driver

Can I connect the outputs of the two Low-Side MOSFET Driver ICs, [MIC4452](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic4451.pdf), in parallel?

Any specific case/thing that I need to take care of?

Comment: Why would you connect them in parallel? Give some details about the application.

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended.
Even though both driver would be tied together at the input (so they switch on/off simultaneously) there will be small differences in timing that will lead them to a shoot-through condition, that is, one of them still in low while the other is already in high state. Maybe only a few nanoseconds. Probably this won’t destroy the drivers, but they will become hot and in the long run they could even fail.